# PHP dates query workaround for text-type field

Tags: php, mysql, database, date

I cannot understand why the following isn't working, and I now realise its because my field-type in MySQL is text...

```
SELECT * 
FROM Scans 
WHERE Date BETWEEN '$sdate' AND '$edate'
```

`$sdate` and `$edate` are defined dates in format of `01/01/2018`. This is also how they are stored in the database under the column `Date`.

Is there any work-around that allows me to date search but with strings and text fields?

Comment: What data type is your “Date” column in the database? Please don’t say a text type …

Comment: Ahh - that'll be the problem then!

Comment: What date format? correct format Y-m-d, for example 2018-08-25

Comment: If you have a text data type here, then values get compared using string comparison rules - and that means character by character, from left to right.

Comment: If only there was a manual

Comment: Need to use typecasting in a query

Comment: If I somehow change to Date type - would my code then work??

Comment: type casting? like this? @MangeshSathe `SELECT * FROM Scans WHERE (Date BETWEEN '(string)$sdate' AND '(string)$edate')` this not safe beter to use prepared statements instead unless you meant data formatting.. Besides there isn't a `(date)` or `(datetime)` typecast in PHP

Comment: *"If I somehow change to Date type - would my code then work??"* - No, because MySQL's DATE works as YYYY-mm-dd.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a work-around then please?

Comment: Why look for a workaround instead of doing it properly and converting your columns to `DATE` columns…?

Comment: I want to bet if you search on stackoverflow with "php change date formatting" or "mysql change date formatting" you should find alot of examples on stackoverflow so this question is really a duplicate.. If you don't know how the functions work search in the manuals.

Comment: "Why look for a workaround instead of doing it properly and converting your columns to DATE columns" Don't forget @deceze changing a datatype in a table might require more application code changes and testing...

Comment: I can't change format to date in table as it works on YYYY-mm-dd, which would be the wrong format for my entries? Making even more of a mess?

Comment: Did you read mine (last) comment? @NathanWinch

Comment: It doesn't matter what "format" a `DATE` has in MySQL. The important part is that MySQL understands it is a *date*, with days and months and years, and indexes that appropriately, and lets you do proper date-range queries. If that requires that you adjust your date format when you do a query from PHP so MySQL understands the date you query for properly, **then so be it.** That doesn't mean you have to change your date formats *everywhere*, you just need to form a proper query. Don't let *that* be the reason not to use `DATE` columns.

Comment: Oh I see... so I change the column anyway and it will understand? I get that text type is stupid. Sorry I'm self-taught...

Comment: One basic idea: each system has many different data types, like numbers, and strings, and dates. These types have different things they can do, e.g. you can ask "between" queries of dates, but not really of text. And since each system (MySQL, PHP, Javascript) has slight difference between these types, there'll always be a need to convert back and forth between strings and native dates and so on. And how you show that to the user is yet another story. Just use the proper types in each system, and convert as necessary. That's simply par for the course.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181885/discussion-on-question-by-nathan-winch-php-dates-query-workaround-for-text-type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your dates into the YYYY-MM-DD format in PHP before building your SQL and then your data within the table like so:

```
$sdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sdate));
$edate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($edate));
```

and in SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Scans 
WHERE str_to_date(`Date`,"%d/%m/%Y") BETWEEN '$sdate' AND '$edate'
```

If you are able to migrate the database fieldtype from `text` to `date` and the migrate the contents then this will allow you to drop the `str_to_date(`Date`,"%d/%m/%Y")` part, but the `$sdate` and `$edate` will still need to be in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

To migrate *safely* means to:

1. create a temp field
2. read from your date column
3. convert to YYYY-MM-DD
4. write it to the temp column
5. change the Date column field type to a date
6. copy the data back
7. remove the temp column

Comment: But all the stored dates in the database are dd/mm/YYYY ..?

Comment: @NathanWinch ok, I've updated the answer to rely on both being changed, which will be required because the YYYY-MM-DD format allows for searching, the day first version will not.

Comment: Thank you - my SQL already exists and has a lot of data in it so I can't really change all the dates in there, but I can change the field type to date?

Comment: @NathanWinch Yes it will, I've added that to the answer.

Comment: I've changed to date type and its deleted all my date information. I'm not please at all. Luckily I've backed up the database....

Comment: I said _migrate_ it, which means to make a controlled change.  I'm glad you made a backup first.

Comment: If you are using a framework, that would be something like: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations - however if not then you would script it from scratch.  So you would create a temp field, read form your date column, convert, write it to the temp column, change the Date column field type, then copy the data back and remove the temp column.

Comment: Okay, I'll do it the hard way!

Comment: Then mark best answer once I can confirm it all works  :-)

Comment: One more question - can I keep the dd/mm/yyyy format in a date field? As further inserts will put it in this way..?

Comment: well no, you'll need to adjust where the date is being inserted and convert it.  You cannot have the Date field and insert a non-formed date into it.  I know this is painful to hear after the fact and there are many comments on your question... everyone has to learn sometimes I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't even know where to start with this... Is there PHP code I could use to just go through and convert it? Then when I change data type it won't be deleted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181888/discussion-between-barry-and-nathan-winch).